# cp: cannot stat ‘share/docs/html’: No such file or directory

Tags: makefile, installation, couchdb

cannot make install couchdb 2
i stuck again  with the docs installation:

Installing CouchDB into //usr/local/lib/couchdb...
==> rel (generate)
WARN:  'generate' command does not apply to directory /root/src/couchdb
cp: cannot stat ‘share/docs/html’: No such file or directory
Makefile:85: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you don't have `man` installed. You can either run `./configure --disable-docs` or install `man` (`apt-get install man` for Ubuntu).

To be sure starting from scratch, you can run

`make clean && ./configure --disable-docs && make release`